# table spanning only one column width in a multicol document

Tags: tables, two-column, width

I have a two-column document and what to inset a table. My problem is that the some of the columns in the table overlaps into the other side column. I have found a [question which deals with generating a column spanning two columns.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251733/table-spanning-two-of-three-columns-in-multicol-environment) But I want to make the table fit within a column width. Any suggestions would be great? Does one have to resize the text or manually specify the column width?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Table formatting}
\author{The geniuses at SE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\doublespacing

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{Introduction}      
\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \captionaboveof{table}{Distribution of XXX}
        \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
            \textbf{Sex} &  \textbf{[0-1]} & \textbf{[1--5)} & \textbf{[5--10)} & \textbf{[10--25)} & \textbf{25-50} & \textbf{[50+]} \\
            \hline
            M & 61\% & 28\% & 4\% & -\% & 6\% & x\% \\
            F & 60\% & 25\% & 5\% & 3\% & 7\% & x\% \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option, where you could just decrease the inter-column spacing; Instead of a regular `\tabcolsep`, I've reduced that to 35% of `\tabcolsep`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Table formatting}
\author{The geniuses at SE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\doublespacing

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{Introduction}      
\lipsum[1-1]

%\addvspace{\intextsep}% You may want to add this...

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \captionaboveof{table}{Distribution of XXX}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.35\tabcolsep}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{7}{c} }
    \toprule
    \textbf{Sex} &  \textbf{[0-1]} & \textbf{[1--5)} & \textbf{[5--10)} & \textbf{[10--25)} & \textbf{[25-50)} & \textbf{[50+]} \\
    \midrule
    M & 61\% & 28\% & 4\% & -\% & 6\% & x\% \\
    F & 60\% & 25\% & 5\% & 3\% & 7\% & x\% \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\addvspace{\intextsep}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Since you included [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), I've used its rules.

Comment: thanks, that seems to do it. Can you suggest any other methods, I am just beginning with latex.

Comment: @lukeg: Alternative methods (this one included) are subjective and depends heavily on what you have in your table. Some people resize the entire `tabular` by wrapping it inside `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{...}`. But that resizes *everything* and not everyone likes it.